# Generating a bin folder in NodeJS with Fedora

Tags: node.js, fedora

I'm learning to do CRUD in Node, and am having trouble generating the bin folder. Also, the package.json folder which I've generated doesn't contain the dependencies needed to run on localhost.

To generate the app, I used `express MyApp`
and then `npm install` `npm install mongoose --save`
This gave me:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
   "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.5.2",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

It did not generate a bin folder, or www file hiding elsewhere. I'm using Fedora 23, in case that makes a difference here. Please let me know if there's something I've missed, or if you have any suggested work-arounds.

Comment: Apologies. The code block is what was generated in MyApp/package.json